# ArcGIS Points to polygons spatial join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I am trying to join points to polygons. To be more precise I have a dataset with points associated with a particular political event. Each point comes with latitude and longitude and other information. And I have a shapefile that has polygons that have regional data information at the Nuts1 level.

I want each of the points to be given the NUTS code in which it belongs to based on latitude and longitude.

I do spatial join on ArcGIS joining points to polygons. I have the same projection in both files. But when the join is completed the data from the polygons do not appear in the joint file. I have the corresponding columns, e.g., Nuts code, or population of this NUTS but all info comes with 0's.

Any suggestions why this happens and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're doing the join the wrong way round. If you want to know what NUTS code is associated with each point, join the polygon to the points. See more information on [Spatial Joins](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) for more information.

If you use python, see the code below.

```
point_fc = r"path_to_point_fc"
polygon_fc = r"path_to_polygon_fc"
SpatialJoin_analysis (point_fc, polygon_fc, "name_of_new_dataset", "JOIN_ONE_TO_MANY", "KEEP_ALL")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried that but what I end up with is a table with the NUTS regions where no information from the points is appended. No clue why this happens. But even if info from the points where appended, still I would get the average of the points at the nuts level. Which is not what I want. What I want is the the nuts in which each point falls within. Meaning that the same nuts may be allocated to several points.

Comment: you would still join the polyon (NUTS) to the points. i think you may need to upload some screenshots of your dataset tables. i cant work out whats wrong otherwise

Comment: Hi, thanks! Managed to do it eventually via the toolbox. No clue why it did not work directly from the right-click menu. But thanks for the feedback and time!